# Can you create a "save file" in a text based game using visual studio c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I just wanted to know if this is possible. I know that I can read and write information from files, but I am wondering if I can apply that for a text based game as well.

Comment: A "text based game" is a program like any other. Of course it can read and write files.

Comment: would it be possible to create like save points in a story based text? I know I can read and write hp, dmg and stuff for an rpg. I want to know if its possible for story?

Comment: At the end of the day, every program is a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You just need to figure out what your program's state is, then it would be easy to save it and to load it back later.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I have an idea.